# How do you trace data dependencies in a Pandas codebase?

Tags: python, pandas, testing, documentation

I'm am looking to document a large Pandas-based OOP codebase (hundreds of methods). Each method can be fairly straight forward, but there is some nesting. I'm looking for a way to programaticaly discover what features in the input DataFrame are needed for each method to work.

Consider this code:

```
def get_perimeter(self):
    return 2*self.df['length'] + 2*self.df['width']

...

def get_total_energy(self):
    potential_energy = self.get_potential_energy()
    kinetic_energy = self.get_kinetic_energy()
    return potential_energy + kinetic_energy
```

I'd be great to get a dictionary of the form:

```
{
 'get_perimeter': ['width', 'height'],
 'get_total_energy': ['velocity', 'height', 'mass', 'g']
}
```

I am considering:

```
dependency_dict = {}

for col in df.columns:
    dependency_dict[col] = []
    df_without_col = df.drop(columns=[col])

    obj = MyObject(df_without_col)
    for calculation in obj.calculations: # a list of the methods
        try:
            # Try and run the method without the column
        except KeyError:
            dependency_dict[col].append(calculation)
  
# Formatting
```

But it hurts my sensibilities. Any ideas?